# SKOBBLER SDK 2.5 play Street name with Audio advice

Tags: android, skmaps, skobbler-maps

Hi I am using SKOBBLER SDK 2.5 (Android). How can i play Street name for Audio instructions while navigation in progress, as of now it plays only distance left and turn left/right.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The general_TTS.adv file defines the rules for creating audio/text instructions for text-to-speech support. The TTS engines can also pronounce street names, you can include this information in the advice via the $nameOrRef (which will return the street’s name of reference, giving priority to the Name tag)
The name, corresponds to whatever is the value of the “name” tag is (i.e. “Tri-State Tollway”, the reference corresponding to whatever the value of the “ref” tag is (i.e. “I 294”). Bundled with the $nameOrRef parameter you have the $hasNameOrRef conditional – if that particular road has a name or a ref value the text following the conditional will be used, otherwise the instruction will stop

For documentation please follow this links: http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/advisor-support-text-to-speech-scout-audio/
http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/advisor-support-text-to-speech-faq/

Comment: Thanks Adrian, i will implement your solution and will share feedback with you!